# Create a JPA many-to-many relation using an id instead of an object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a large dataset which I am importing in bulk with rows looking like

```
(news_id, category_id_1, category_id_2, ..., category_id_9)
```

Each `category_id_x` is an integer from a fixed set of categories.

I want to map these multiple categories into a m2m relation for quicker searching.

I have a `News` table and a `Category` table.

The `Category` table maps category ids to category names.

I already have all the mappings setup in JPA for the various `News` fields, and I want to reuse this code.

My question is how can I import these m2m relations in JPA.

I was thinking along the lines of the following but I get errors saying that you can't create Category objects manually.

```
// News object
@Entity
@Table(name = "news", schema = "public", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class News implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields
    @Column(name = "asx_code")
    private String asxCode;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "annnum", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String annnum;
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;
    ...
    ...
    @ManyToMany() 
    @JoinTable(name="announcement_types", 
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="annnum"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="report_type"))
    private Collection<ReportType> reportType;

function m(String) {
    // extract and return data from datasource
}

// Create a news object from 9 different report types
News o = new News();        
java.util.Collection<ReportType> types = new HashSet(); 
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType0"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType1"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType2"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType3"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType4"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType5"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType6"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType7"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType8"))));
types.add(new ReportType(toInt(m("RepType9"))));
o.setReportType(types);

// Query
try {
    EntityTransaction entr = em.getTransaction();
    entr.begin();           
    em.persist(row); # row is our News object
    entr.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
return true;

// ERROR
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: edu.unsw.eventstudy.shared.dto.ReportType
```

---

EDIT:

Seems I am dealing with the concept of detached entities. This is solved in Hibernate using the unsaved-value mapping or isSaved property. Now looking for a solution in JPA.

Comment: Please copy your full error message, and the piece of code which triggers it.

Comment: Added code above. Basically for each news item i want to create entries in the second table for all their report types however the entries already exist in the second table and I already know the keys to associate.

Answer (score 0):

I only see the association in 1 direction. Maybe you forgot to do the other one, like:
reportType0.add(news);
reportType1.add(news);
...
reportTypeN.add(news);

Also, you are "creating" instances of the ReportType instead of gathering them from the database. Do they already exist in the database?

Comment: Yes they already exist in the database. I want to create News objects without having to lookup the ReportType mappings from the database as I already have the primary keys in my import data set.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think you do need to gather the ReportType instances from the database, and update their collection of News.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid though because it seems pointless to get ReportTypes from the db as I already have their primary keys.

Comment: As of today, did you find a better solution than mine?